# Can't install plug-ins from CP

Tags: plugins, cli

I can install plug-ins from the command line, but when I do so from within Craft, I get this:

**Composer was unable to install the updates.**

Error: Could not delete /var/www/craft-dev/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-shell/ShellController.php: unlink(/var/www/craft-dev/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-shell/ShellController.php): Permission denied

Composer output: Package "craftcms/vue-asset" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Package operations: 8 installs, 2 updates, 4 removals

- Removing yiisoft/yii2-shell (2.0.4)

Any suggestions? Permission error?

Comment: Likely a permissions issue... what user:group owns `/var/www/craft-dev/vendor` and what user:group does your web server run as?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, looks like you'll need to look at the folder yiisoft and subfolders for permissions. Maybe set them to read, write until you're done and then change them to read only.

Just thinking off the top of my head about what the issue could be.